# incorrectly drafted MongoDB aggregation pipeline $match stage

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, mongo-go

I'm trying to make a query in golang language (below I've attached working code of pure mongodb query) using `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo` library, below is golang query code. I can't get `matchStage` to work correctly, I've tried many variants and I'm sure I'm just very inattentive or just don't understand

How can I use `$match`, `$expr`, `$and` and `$lte` at once to make a correct `matchStage`?

```golang
func (r *Mongo) ChatHistory(ctx context.Context, chatID string, f *Filter) ([]*Message, error) {
    matchStage := bson.D{
        primitive.E{
            Key: "$match",
            Value: bson.D{
                primitive.E{Key: "$expr", Value: bson.D{
                    primitive.E{Key: "$and", Value: bson.A{
                        bson.D{
                            primitive.E{Key: "$lte", Value: bson.D{
                                primitive.E{
                                    Key:   "$create_date",
                                    Value: f.Date, // int64
                                },
                            }},
                        },
                    }},
                }},
            },
        },
    }
    sortStage := bson.D{
        {
            Key: "$sort", Value: bson.D{
                primitive.E{Key: "create_date", Value: -1},
            },
        },
    }
    limitStage := bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "$limit", Value: f.Count}}

    cursor, err := r.colMessage.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{matchStage, sortStage, limitStage})
    if err != nil {
        l.Error().Err(err).Msg("failed find")
        return nil, err
    }

    var res []*Message
    if err = cursor.All(ctx, &res); err != nil {
        l.Error().Err(err).Msg("failed find all documents")
        return nil, err
    }

    if err = cursor.Close(ctx); err != nil {
        l.Error().Err(err).Msg("failed close cursor")
        return nil, err
    }

    return res, nil
}
```

**Error:** `(InvalidPipelineOperator) Unrecognized expression '$create_date'`

[MongoDB playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YFXqlrd67o4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value of `$lte` must be an array not a document:

```
matchStage := bson.D{
    primitive.E{
        Key: "$match",
        Value: bson.D{
            primitive.E{Key: "$expr", Value: bson.D{
                primitive.E{Key: "$and", Value: bson.A{
                    bson.D{
                        primitive.E{Key: "$lte", Value: bson.A{
                            "$create_date",
                            f.Date, // int64
                        }},
                    },
                }},
            }},
        },
    },
}
```

Also note that you can leave out the `primitive.E` type from the composite literal:

```
matchStage := bson.D{
    {
        Key: "$match",
        Value: bson.D{
            {Key: "$expr", Value: bson.D{
                {Key: "$and", Value: bson.A{
                    bson.D{
                        {Key: "$lte", Value: bson.A{
                            "$create_date",
                            f.Date, // int64
                        }},
                    },
                }},
            }},
        },
    },
}
```

But note that your expression on the mongo playground is incorrect. Quoting from the [doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-match):

> [`$match`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-match) takes a document that specifies the query conditions. The query syntax is identical to the [read operation query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#std-label-read-operations-query-argument) syntax
> ...

When using `$expr`, you have to use `$eq`, for example:

```
matchStage := bson.D{
    {
        Key: "$match",
        Value: bson.D{
            {Key: "$expr", Value: bson.D{
                {Key: "$and", Value: bson.A{
                    bson.D{
                        {Key: "$eq", Value: bson.A{
                            "$chat_id",
                            chatID,
                        }},
                    },
                    bson.D{
                        {Key: "$lte", Value: bson.A{
                            "$create_date",
                            f.Date, // int64
                        }},
                    },
                }},
            }},
        },
    },
}
```

Try it here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/SBEJD-Fyhjl

You should use a normal query document in `$match`.

See this equivalent, much simpler solution:

```
matchStage := bson.D{
    {
        Key: "$match",
        Value: bson.D{
            {Key: "chat_id", Value: chatID},
            {Key: "create_date", Value: bson.D{
                {
                    Key:   "$lte",
                    Value: f.Date, // int64
                }},
            },
        },
    },
}
```

And even much-much simpler if you use `bson.M` instead of `bson.D`:

```
matchStage := bson.M{
    "$match": bson.M{
        "chat_id":     chatID,
        "create_date": bson.M{"$lte": f.Date},
    },
}
```

Of course in this last case you can't use `mongo.Pipeline` for the pipeline, but `[]any` or `[]bson.M` would also do.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you tell me why, in my [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JMXkIkHVpJE) I get not only those messages which should get by the condition `chat_id: "b199ceba-78bb-4204-859e-5a1be228b2b5"` but also other messages with completely different chat IDs. How can I fix it?

Comment: @alex Because inside `$expr`, you have to use `$eq` for equality. See my edited answer, included an example (with mongo playground link).